# Why a homomorphism from full Galois group of rationals cannot factor.

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

I need to fully understand why if I have epimorphism $f: G_{\Bbb Q}\to \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$ , with  $\;\Bbb G_{\Bbb Q}=\;$ full Galois group of rationals $\;\Bbb Q\;$ , and when last group corresponds with extension  $\;\Bbb Q(i)/\Bbb Q\;$, then it cannot factor through (sub)group  $\;\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\;$ …?

My idea is that if exists  $\;g:\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$ such that  $\;f=g\pi\;$ , with $\;\pi:G_{\Bbb Q}\to\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\;$ , then $\;\Bbb Q\;$ must have cyclic extension of order $\;4\;$ (corresponding to $\;\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\;$) which also contains extension $\;\Bbb Q(i)/\Bbb Q\;$, and this is impossible as then it must contain $\;i\;$ . This very last I completely understand, but the factoring fact corresponding to cyclic extension containing $\;i\;$ still isn't clear to me very much, though I think (feel is more exact) that this is pretty close to truth as I "feel" like $\;\pi\;$ should be canonical projection...

Any idea can be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your epimorphism $f: G_{\mathbf Q} \to Gal(\mathbf Q(i)/\mathbf Q)$ cannot factor through $\mathbf Z/4$  is equivalent to saying that $\mathbf Q(i)$ cannot be embedded in a cyclic Galois extension of $\mathbf Q$ of degree $4$. For simplicity, write $K=\mathbf Q(i)$ and consider a chain of successive quadratic extensions $\mathbf Q < K < L$. Since we are in characteristic $\neq 2$, $L$ has the form $L=K(\sqrt a)$, where $a\in K^*$ and $a\notin {K^*}^2$. A priori $L/\mathbf Q$ is not always normal. A necessary and sufficient condition for normality is that $\gamma (a)/a \in {K^*}^2$, where $\gamma$ is the complex conjugation of $K$. (*Hint*: The splitting field of $X^2 - a$ over $\mathbf Q$ is obtained by adjoining to $\mathbf Q$ the roots of $X^2 - a$ and $X^2 - \gamma(a)$. It coincides with $L$ iff $\gamma (a)/a \in {K^*}^2$).

If $L/\mathbf Q$ is normal of degree $4$, its Galois group is either $(\mathbf Z/2)\times (\mathbf Z/2)$ or $\mathbf Z/4$. To distinguish between the two cases, note that the normality condition can be written as $\gamma (a)/a =x^2$, with $x\in K^*$, so $N(x)=\pm 1$, where $N$ is the norm of $K/\mathbf Q$. The condition $N(x)=1$ means that $x$ has the form $x=\gamma(b)/b$ (Hilbert's thm.90 or direct computation), hence $\gamma(ab^2)=ab^2$, or equivalently $ab^2=c\in\mathbf Q^*$, i.e. $L$ has the form $L=\mathbf Q (i, \sqrt c)$, with Galois group $(\mathbf Z/2)\times (\mathbf Z/2)$. The remaining condition $N(x)=-1$ means that $-1$ is the sum of 2 squares of rationals : impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yet I understand why $\;i\;$ cannot be contained in a cyclic extension of order 4. My problem is with the first two lines: why is that equivalence true? As I explained in my question, I sort of "see it" but I need to make completely formal.

Comment: Is the "equivalence" problem in the "first two lines" of your §1 ? It seems to me straightforward that the existence of the epimorphisms $f,g,\pi$ s.t. $f=g.\pi$ means the existence of a cyclic extension $L/\mathbf Q$ of degree $4$ containing $\mathbf Q(i)$ : by definition, $L$ (resp. $\mathbf Q(i)$) is fixed by Ker$\pi$ (resp. Ker$f$), and $f=g.\pi$ implies that Ker$f$ contains Ker$\pi$. Note in passing that $\mathbf Z /4$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbf Z /2$, but $\mathbf Z /2$ is a quotient of $\mathbf Z /4$ instead.

Comment: Finally, the property stated at the end of the first sentence of your §2 is not at all obvious, as shown by the demonstration that I gave.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem: how to **fully** justify the non-existence of that factoring...and yes: I also think it is more or less straightforward...but how to do justification? I know $\;G_{\Bbb Q}\;$ is inverse limit of Galois groups of finite Galois extensions of $\;\Bbb Q\;'$ , but is this enough to justify? And why? Thanks.

Comment: You have nothing to justify since you accept the existence of the absolute Galois group $G_Q$ (no matter how it is justified). By one of the main theorems of Galois theory, this implies that every $Gal(k/Q)$ is a quotient of $G_Q$. In (your) other words, $G_Q$ is the inverse limit of its finite quotients. Then eveything concerning the epimorphisms and their factoring is genuinely straightforward. But I insist that the second property (non existence of etc.) is genuinely *not* straightforward !

Comment: @nguyee Do you mean non existence of cyclic extension of order 4 containing $\;i\;$ ? I don't think that is trivial but it is easy to show, and don't need Hilbert's 90th Th.  or something complicated: if $\;\sigma\in\,$ Aut$\,(L)\;$ , then $\;\sigma^2i=\sigma(i^2)=\sigma(-1)=-1\implies \sigma\;$ must be complex conjugation, and fixed field of $\;H=\langle\sigma\rangle\;$ is $\;L^H=L\cap\Bbb R\;$ is extension of order two of $\;\Bbb Q\;$ ….but also $\;\Bbb Q(i)\;$ extension of order two! This is impossible because cyclic extensions have one *unique* extension of each order.

Comment: I don't understand why $s^2(i)=s(i^2)$. As I see it, suppose that $Gal(L/Q)$ is cyclic of order 4, generated by $s$. Then $s^2$ has order 2 and fixes $Q(i)$, and that's all you can say a priori.

Comment: That was meant to be $\;(\sigma i)^2=\sigma(i)\sigma(i)=\sigma(i^2)=…\;$ , and it was *any* non-trivial element in the automorphism group of the assumed cyclic group of order four. From $\;(\sigma i)^2=-1\implies \sigma i=\pm i\;$ . But it can't be $\;\sigma i=i\;$ since then $\;\sigma\;$ fixes $\;\Bbb Q(i)\;$ and the fixed field of the automorphism group is $\;\Bbb Q\;$ , so it must be $\;\sigma i=-i\implies\;$ conjugation. I didn't show all the steps, sorry.

Comment: I agree if you replace your previous $s^2 (i)$ by $s(i)^2$, hence $s(i)=\pm i$. *If* we  take $s$ of order 4, I agree that $s(i)=-i$, i.e. the restriction of $s$ to $Q(i)$ is the complex conjugation of $Q(i)$. But from this you cannot conclude anything about the action of $s$ on $L$. A priori $L= Q(i) (\alpha)$, and any $z \in L$  is uniquely written as $z=x+y\alpha$, with $x, y \in Q(i)$, and all you get is $s(z)=\bar x+ \bar y s(\alpha)$. I think that you got carried away by the ambiguous term "complex conjugation". Your argument would work in a biquadratic field, but without contradiction.

Comment: I think I understand your point. But $\;si=-i\;,\;\;s^2=Id\implies H= \langle s\rangle\;$ is a subgroup of order two, which corresponds with fixed field of conjugation  $\;L^H=L\cap\Bbb R\;$ which is extension of $\;\Bbb Q\;$ of order two. But also $\;\Bbb Q(i)\;$ is extension of order two, and this is impossible as the extension is cyclic and then there is one unique extension of each order...

Comment: No again. That $s(i)=-i$ implies only that the square of the *restriction* of $s$ to $Q(i)$ is $Id$, not $s^2 =Id$. Confusion arises because you lack care in the definition of what you call "automorphisms". In case of doubt you should always write $Gal(K/k)$, with precisely in mind what $K$ and $k$ are. In your "proof", you are probably thinking of $K=$ previous $L$ and $k=Q(i)$, so your "impossibility" is tautological. When I alluded to a biquadratic field, I meant $k= $ another quadratic field $\neq Q(i)$, so that $L=k(i)$ and your argument works, but leads to no contradiction.

Comment: I add a detailed cyclic example to show where you went wrong. Consider the 5-th cyclotomic field $L=Q(\zeta_5)$, which is cyclic of degree 4. Fix a generator $g$ of $G=Gal(L/Q)$. The complex conjugation $c$ in $L$, defined by $c(i)=-i$, is no other than $g^2$, and its fixed field is $K=Q(cos(2\pi/5))=Q(\sqrt 5)$, a real quadratic field s.t. $L=Q(i)$. The restriction of $g$ to $K$, say $\bar g$, generates $Gal(K/Q)$ (which is a quotient of $G$, not a subgroup) and is defined by $\bar g (\sqrt 5)=-\sqrt 5$. Note that $c$ lives in a subgroup of $G$, and $\bar g$ in a quotient ...

Comment: ... You could repeat word for word your previous argument, replacing what you called the complex conjugation by $g$ and get $g(\sqrt 5)=\pm \sqrt 5$, so actually $g(\sqrt 5)=- \sqrt 5$ because $\sqrt 5 \notin Q$, and $g^2(\sqrt 5)=\sqrt 5$. But we knew that, since $g^2=c$ fixes $K$, and there is no contradiction. There is an apparent contradiction only if you confuse $g$ and $\bar g$